# Angular child directive does not reflect changes in parent property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular and trying to get the hang of breaking up my content into directives. It is working fairly well so far, except that in one place where I pass a collection from the parent to the child, it only seems to get passed successfully during linking.

So my object looks a little like this:

```
var comment = {
    title: "Hello",
    author: "Clever Hans",
    likes: [ { userId: 12, name: "Alice" }, { userId: 15, name: "Bob"} ]
};
```

In my template I have something looking a like this:

```
<div id="comment-container">
    <h3>{{comment.title}}</h3>
    <p>By {{comment.author}}</p>
    <div>{{comment.likes.length}} likes: </div>
    <like-list comment-likes="comment.likes"></like-list>
</div>
```

Then I have a second child directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.components').directive('likeList', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          scope: {
              commentLikes: '='
          },
          link: function( scope, element, parameters ) {
                // ????
          }
      }
});
```

The problem I have is that when my `comment` object gets updated with an extra `like` being added the corresponding template updates as you would expect, but the `likeList` directive does not. The count property changes on the parent template, but I can't figure out how to organise the child so that the update is passed through. I've tried setting up a watch on the `commentLikes` property, but a) doing that on a local property seems weird and b) it doesn't work. What should I be doing to ensure that my nested directive changes when it is supposed to?

Comment: nothing showing for how you add new ones.  A [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo would also help

Comment: Does it matter how new ones are added? I use a watch on a service property to pick up changes, but if the parent scope knows that the item has changed and updates the parent directive's content accordingly doesn't that strongly imply that the problem is in the communication between the parent and child directive? Genuine question - if there is another reason this could happen it would be good to know about it.

Comment: Note that pushing  a new object into the likes array should be bound right through to the directive

Comment: My guess is that your data is being updated outside angular context. What is currently shown should not require any watches but if anything changes scope from outside angular you need to notify angular to run a digest